# C Programming - Integer value within struct becomes "random" after assignment

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I've searched for a fix to this issue but haven't been able to find an explanation. I have a two dimensional struct which has an integer variable within it.

```
typedef struct
{
    int example;

} Example;

typedef struct
{
    Example two_dimensional_array[5][5];
} Example_Outer;
```

I then set this variable to 0 for all fields using the following function and print the current values.

```
void initialise(Example_Outer example)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            example.two_dimensional_array[i][j].example = 0;
        }
    }

    print_example(example);

}
```

During this print, the values all appear as 0's like they should.

Output:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

I then run a new function that utilises the exact same print code, and receive the following output:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 
0, -394918304, 32551, -2138948520, 32764, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1775692253, 
21904, -394860128, 32551, 0, 0, 
1775692176, 21904, 1775691312, 21904, -2138948320,
```

print method:

```
void print_example(Example_Outer example)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            printf("%d, ", example.two_dimensional_array[i][j].example);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

main method:

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{   
    Example_Outer example;
    initialise(example);
    printf("---------------\n");
    print_example(example);

}
```

Why do the variables not remain set to 0? What is causing this and how can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: `initialize()` uses its own copy of the struct. Any changes within the function are not reflected on the copy of the calling function. You may want to pass in a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can initialize your struct like bellow in a simple way :

```
Example_Outer example = { 0 };
```

Or in second way :

```
typedef struct
{
    Example two_dimensional_array[5][5] = { 0 };
} Example_Outer;
```

Now in your code , you forgot about `*` in your `void initialise(Example_Outer example)` function, and in this case you just passing a copy of struct in function.

So you should use of struct's address as parameter to the function with pointer (`*`) :

```
void initialise(Example_Outer *example)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            example->two_dimensional_array[i][j].example = 0;
        }
    }

    print_example(*example);
}
```

Finally you can pass your struct's address as following : ( **[Test it online](http://cpp.sh/4g74j)** ) :

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Example_Outer example;
    initialise(&example);
    printf("---------------\n");
    print_example(example);

}
```

Comment: The issue isn't how to initialise a struct, but why the function doesn't modify it.